how to extract the first image from blog post for thumbnail ? custom code in the first-generation classic theme on Blogger
I've been attempting to display snippets of all the posts on one page using the classic first-generation Blogger theme. However, I haven't found any specific tags to create post snippets.
I want to display thumbnails and excerpts only, similar to what is seen in the second-generation Blogger theme image linked below. I've searched extensively but have not yet found a solution.
Template theme - first generation classic from 2004

I want to display thumbnails and excerpts only for featured posts, but in the classic theme, featured posts are listed with the complete body of the post. How can I achieve this?
